# How to read from a Azure Data Warehouse into Python using Databricks?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, dataframe

I tested some sample code that I found online.  This is it.

```
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc 

conn =  "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=name.database.windows.net;DATABASE=db_name;UID=my_id;PWD=my_pwd"

df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from dbo.main_table', conn)
```

So, I would expect this to import the dataset, that sites in SQL Server, into the dataframe, but I'm getting this error.

```
ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=etc., etc., etc.
```

I'm working in a Databricks environment.  Thanks for the look.